# BackupExec stuck at discovering devices

Tags: backupexec

After restarting BackupExec 21.4 server, I can't start any backup job because the server is stuck in "Discovering devices".

I already tried googling but every suggestion is to just restart the server/services again (which I tried but obviously didn't work).

It has been stuck in this state for an hour now.

Should I just wait and hope or is there anything better to try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, I just had to wait and hope!

After about 2 hours, everything started working back as normal.